# Price next to product title [woocommerce]

Tags: php, css, function, woocommerce, product

I have this function and I want to add next to the product price.
I used `get_price_html()` and `$price = $product->get_price_html`

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
echo '<h4 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>'; }
```

**Current Output**

[image: Current Output]

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: That's great. Can you explain exactly what is not working ?

Comment: I can't get this: Product name: Price, i have only Product name. When i adding to code variables code have errors and website doesn't work

e.g. Hoodie $36

Comment: Your code is only retrieving the title ( `get_the_title()` ) Have you tried looking for the function that returns the price and add it to your string ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an action to change the title.  So I wrote this code for you, simply add this to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'the_title', 'add_price_title' );

function add_price_title($title) {
 $post_ID = get_the_ID();
 $the_post = get_post($post_ID);
 $date = $the_post->post_date;
 $maintitle = $the_post->post_title;
 $count='';
 $product = wc_get_product( $post_ID );
 $price = $product->get_price();


if ($the_post->post_status == 'publish' AND $the_post->post_type == 'product' AND in_the_loop()) { 
 return "<span type='number' class='notbold'>".$title." $".$price.""."</span>";
}

else{
 return $title;   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// define the woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title callback 
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
    global $product;
    echo '<p>'.get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_price', true).'</p>';
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
global $product;
$price = $product->get_price_html();
echo '<h4 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title h-price">' . get_the_title() .'&nbsp'. $price .'</h4>';}
```

My answer.